# Facebook curl like post request using open graph

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to create the like button in my `iOS` app by using

```
curl -X POST \
  -F 'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -F 'object=OG_OBJECT_URL' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og
```

.likes  given by `Open graph api`.

For it I have made post request i.e.

```
  NSString *stringurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{access_token=AAAE08AxGmwghghghOWAxMZBz6jZAaRTUYTRMakJln3VdAeUju6E6tFn2I9feY5wtGatTm2KIgXoXYFZB0pTPQt2Oj0sNaRuX3AZDZD}&{object=http://www.google.com}&https://graph.facebook.com/100002097766610/og.likes"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: stringurl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request1 setURL:url];
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request1 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string..:%@",string);
```

But I am getting empty string. May be I am making wrong url string. If any one know that how to make the curl post request. Please give me some idea.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I attached some codes below:

Body data of Http POST request should located in 'Body', So I used 'setHttpBody:' method.

```
NSString *userId = @"Your ID Facebook ID";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/og.likes", userId]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request1 setURL:url];
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *body=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&object=OG_OBJECT_URL"];
[request1 setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string..:%@",string);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great coding.. I was trying to resolve this issue from last one week.. and You have solved it. You make my day today.